# multidimensional config in config.php file

Tags: php, codeigniter, config

I am using codeigniter framework and I want to access a multidimensional config variable from config.php.
For Example:

$config['user']['students']['cs'] = 'CS USERS';

To access 1-dimensional array i can do like this:
$this->config->item('user').
But how can i access this multidimensional config variable.

Regards,
      Aby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you config you just do something like this:

```
$config['test']['one'] = 'one';
$config['test']['two'] = 'two';
$config['test']['three'] = 'three';
```

And whey you do `$this->config->item('test');` you just get an array which is:

```
Array
(
    [one] => one
    [two] => two
    [three] => three
)
```

Comment: can i do for this config  $config['user']['students']['cs'] ?

Comment: Yep, it just return an array to you.